# Jira cloud REST API - Set default value of system field

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin

How can I set the default value of the description field of a Jira issue using the [Jira cloud REST API.](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/intro/#about)

When the create issue form is opened, I would like the description field of that issue to be pre-filled with some content, which can then be edited.

I can't seem to find any reference to setting default values for *system* fields (the fields that all Jira issues contain by default, e.g. title, description, components, etc.) in the REST API documentation.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you want to change the field value whenever that Create screen is opened.
You could try the [Script Runner Behaviors](https://docs.adaptavist.com/sr4jc/latest/features/behaviours#:%7E:text=Behaviours%20give%20you%20added%20control,given%20project%20or%20issue%20context.)